# equivalent hql query? (query with nested query in FROM clause)

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, hql

what i need:
requests are made out of stages, each stage has starts and ends at a certain time.
i need to know how many requests took the same amount of time to complete (sum of delta of all child stages which are in status finished)

the following sql query gives me the result i need, but it has a nested query in the from clause (which is not allowed in hql)

```
SELECT dist, count(*)
FROM
(
 SELECT S.parentRequestId, sum(S.finishedAt - S.startedAt) as dist
 FROM blarhg.Stage S
 WHERE S.status='FINISHED'
 GROUP BY S.parentRequestId
) qin
GROUP BY dist;
```

how can i achieve the same result in hql?

Answer (score 0):

Every technology has its limits. HQL is no exception: There are some queries that can not be expresses as HQL.

In situations like this, I just use [`createNativeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29), which accepts regular SQL, and move on.